# Getting variables from the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a URL that looks like that:

"~/ControlPanel.aspx?x=usersName"

Now I want the master page to also be able to request the usersName:

string name= Request["x"];

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

you can get using `Request.QueryString["x"];`

```
string name= Request.QueryString["x"];
```

Comment: So there shouldnt be a problem...even though i program at the masterpage?

Comment: @Dmitry, didn't you even try?